# How to join segments of an image mask without distorting dimensions?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing, mask

I've got a mask of an area of interest in an image that I'm attempting to measure. But these masks are not always of high quality and sometimes my objects of interest (whales from drone imagery) come in multiple image segments separated by a couple pixels. So I'm trying to do some dilation and erosion operations to make a single mask but too much dilation then throws off my final measurements. Is there a way to do dilation to join shapes, erosion to take off all the added girth/length from the dilation, but prevent the erosion from creating two distinct segments?

Here is what I currently have:

```
import cv2
# my_mask = output from Mask RCNN
plt.imshow(my_mask, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

[image: first image]

```
mask_uint = np.array(my_mask, dtype=np.uint8)

kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(mask_uint, kernel, iterations=5)

plt.imshow(dilation, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

[image: second image]

```
erosion = cv2.erode(dilation, kernel, iterations=4)

plt.imshow(erosion, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

[image: image three]

And you can see at the end it is still two separate segments, if I do fewer erosion iterations then the mask is far too wide and my measurements of the mask are too distorted.

UPDATE

I tried to change my system to use opencv's minAreaRect() function to measure the length and this lead to a clean looking solution but it adds a pretty considerable buffer leading to very poor length measurements.

[image: image four]

Comment: First question: why do you need them to be connected together? There's probably a lot of possible ways to connect the two shapes, but there's not enough info here to give you the "best" way to connect for your purposes without some more info of the precise metric you actually need.

Comment: You could try different shaped kernels; a cross or diagonal stripe might help in this particular case

Comment: Or asymmetric kernels; a larger dilation kernel and a smaller erosion kernel might work.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I need them to be together because I am taking this mask and using it to measure length and girth of the object. So these gaps create an area where I can't measure girth. Basically I want to interpolate from those edges to complete the shape so I can measure it.

Comment: Why can't you just take the two masks together and measure the length and girth with that directly? Using a `minAreaRect()` on your mask with the two sections would give you the length and girth. If you want to "add" some stuff to your image and then measure it, the measurement is just going to be whatever you add. Doesn't seem like the appropriate thing to do.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I need to take girth at 5% intervals throughout the mask perpendicular to the length axis. So in order to not get a null value where the mask doesn't exist I want to interpolate it. So I think you're right overall, I'm just measuring what I'm adding in but I need some method of interpolation.

Comment: another method instead of dilation to connect the two blobs: try finding distance between two blobs if it is below some threshold value then connect them e.g. `if (dist < 10):  img[100:110,200:250] = 1`

Comment: I see. Well, I'm not trying to be a PITA, but I think if you better define what "interpolation" means here, how you should connect them will directly fall out of that. As it stands, there are a bunch of ways you could connect the two (for instance, getting the distance from each pixel in mask 1 to mask 2, and only drawing ones under a certain "close enough" distance). But this is currently ill-posed as it stands. Also, can you show the code you used for your `minAreaRect()`? I've never seen one that far off before, perhaps you're drawing it with some thickness on the borders?

Comment: The nice thing about `minAreaRect()` if you can get it to work is it will give you the angle over which to find the girth at tons of points throughout the whale. To clarify my above comments, I understand what you're trying to do, but I don't know what is the best metric for you---I think you'd need to decide what constraints you want for connecting them, and then hopefully the problem becomes well-defined and then a solution can be worked out.